# Create expression that return new dynamic anonymous object

Tags: c#, .net, lambda

I want to know if is it possible to "concat" two expressions or more to return a new one that returns a new anonymous object based on those expressions.

My final goal is to provide a list of expression and obtain at the end one expression that return an object with all the property in an new object.

I know it's not very clear, but the sample of code bellow should help you understand.

Thanks in advance !

```cs
Expression<Func<Person, Object>> expr1 = x => x.Age;
Expression<Func<Person, Object>> expr2 = x => x.Name;

//I want this 

Expression<Func<Person, Object>> expr = x => { x.Age, x.Name }
```

Comment: would `Expression<Func<Person, Object>> expr = x => new { x.Age, x.Name }` not work?

Comment: Yeah of course it works, but I want it dynamic, expr1 & expr2 are not always the same, and at the end, it will be a list of expressions ! But thanks for the answer

Comment: This would be not an easy thing, as `x => { x.Age, x.Name }` creates a new class underneath (compiler creates an anonymous class, which you need to create manually somehow)

Comment: @TvanB I think the point is that the OP wants a way to combine `expr1` and `expr2` dynamically, rather than writing a new single line of code to do so.  But OP - what is your plan for such an object?  You wouldn't have access to properties in code etc - [what's the intended use case, there might be an alternative approach](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Expressions would always return a property? or perhaps a method or constant value too?

Comment: @JamesThorpe The use case : I want to allow the user to chose which data he wants to display from the class Person. But this class contains a looot of data and it takes too long to retrieve them all from the database at the same time so I cant simply get all the column and then filter them.

Comment: @VladiPavelka Always a property

Comment: @LePetitPrince so you intend to use this in EF query, where you .Select() into an anonymous obj, querying the DB for just the selected properties? that's why you need it to be Expression<Func>

Comment: @VladiPavelka Exactly !

Comment: @LePetitPrince how do you plan to map from what user selects into Expression<Func> of that property?

Comment: @VladiPavelka I got a list of object with a bool that tells me if the field is selected or not and an expression like this one: x => x.[FieldName] (where x is of type Person)

Comment: @LePetitPrince I'm not sure if this is possible in C#, fundamentally, as (afaik) for each anonymous object there is a class generated at the *compile time* behind the scenes.. I don't know for sure though, am interested in answers here

Comment: Yeah my current approch it's too manipulate the expression body and try to create a new one based on the other but I still did'nt find the right approch. Thank you for your time, I'll keep you updated if I find any solution...

Comment: @LePetitPrince oki, I wish you success! as I said, my guess would be that it is not possible to create anonymous type at runtime, as it's "type" needs to be known (and generated) at compile time